# Floating Action Button not sticked to its parent element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI v4](https://v4.mui.com/) libraries to build a React Js app.

I create a custom Floating Action Button (FAB) component.

The FAB component (the red box in the picture below) must be sticked to the bottom right (with some margins) of its parent element which is the Flyout component (the blue box in the picture below).

The Fylout component has some children inside of it. They are the title, the Content component (sample Card component from Material UI), and the FAB component.

The Flyout component must have an `absolute position` and be scrollable (`scroll: 'auto'`) for its root element because of some reason (I couldn't mention them here).

I use `absolute position` for the FAB component. The result is fine (when the Card is not expanded) as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

But when the Card component is expanded and we scroll the Flyout component, the FAB component is not sticked more from its parent as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried to use `position: 'sticky'` for the FAB component with `bottom: 20` and `right: 20`, but the FAB is not sticked to the bottom right of the Flyout component as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

So my question is **how to make the FAB button sticked only to the bottom right of the Flyout component**?

Here is the simplified code: https://codesandbox.io/s/fab-stick-to-parent-w5ng3

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I have to make this an answer.

Replacing `position: absolute;` with `position: fixed;` worked for me.

An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

Final code:

```
makeStyles-addButton-9 {
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: that's correct that we can use `position: fixed` for the FAB component but the FAB will be fixed only to the viewport not fixed to the parent FAB's parent element (the Flyout component).